# I need regular expression to get substring

Tags: regex

```
Started transaction at 10.12.2014 16:11:02 +02:00
UPDATE [dbo].[Urun]
SET [Ad] = @0, [Kategori] = @1
WHERE ([Id] = @2)

-- @0: 'Erkan' (Type = String, Size = 75)

-- @1: 'Karabulut' (Type = String, Size = 50)

-- @2: '1' (Type = String, Size = 25)

-- Executing asynchronously at 10.12.2014 16:11:02 +02:00

-- Completed in 4 ms with result: 1

Committed transaction at 10.12.2014 16:11:02 +02:00
```

That is my String . I need substring first after [dbo]. means ı need table name and the second datetime.I need regex for both them.

Output

```
"Urun" and "10.12.2014 16:11:02 +02:00"
```

Thanks for help...

Comment: That's nice. Good luck figuring it out. Did you have a question, or are you just expecting us to do your job for you?

Comment: ı have short time . ı couldnt find proper regex for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below regex and get the strings you want from group index 1 and 2.

```
(?s)\[dbo\].*?\[([^\]]*)\].*?\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*?\b(\d{2}\.\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\S+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/39)

Added an alernative because i don't know which date and time you mean.

```
(?s)\[dbo\].*?\[([^\]]*)\].*?\b(\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\s+\S+)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nL5yL3/40)

`(?s)` Dotall modifier which makes dot in your regex to match even line breaks.